# How to merge multiple CSV files based on specific column IDs

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, csv, merge

```
import pandas as pd

videos_list = {
        'Video ID': ['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc'],
        'Title': ['Video Title AAA', 'Video Title BBB', 'Video Title CCC'],
        'Views': ['100', '30', '60']}

transcripts_list = {
        'Title': ['Video Title AAA', 'Video Title CCC'],
        'Video ID': ['aaa', 'ccc'],
        'Rating': ['99', '33']}

videos = pd.DataFrame(videos_list)
transcripts = pd.DataFrame(transcripts_list)

## VIEW Videos and Transcript TABLES
print('--- VIDEOS:\n',list(videos.columns.values),'\n',videos.head(5),'\n')
print('--- Transcripts:\n',list(transcripts.columns.values),'\n',transcripts.head(5),'\n')


## Remove 'Title' from transcripts
transcript_cols = [
    'Video ID',
    'Rating',
    ]
transcript_reindex = transcripts.reindex(columns=transcript_cols)
print('--- Transcript Reindex:\n',list(transcript_reindex.columns.values),'\n',transcript_reindex.head(5),'\n')


## Merge videos + transcript_reindex
transcript_video = pd.merge(videos, transcript_reindex, left_on='Video ID', right_on='Video ID')
print('Video + Transcript:\n',list(transcript_video.columns.values),'\n',transcript_video.head(5))
transcript_video.to_excel('Results.xlsx', index=False, na_rep='')
```

The above code works correctly to produce the following results:

| Video ID | Title | Views | Rating |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| aaa | Video Title AAA | 100 | 99 |
| ccc | Video Title CCC | 60 | 33 |

However, I need to produce the results as shown below:

| Video ID | Title | Views | Rating |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| aaa | Video Title AAA | 100 | 99 |
| bbb | Video Title BBB | 30 |  |
| ccc | Video Title CCC | 60 | 33 |

How can I do that?

Comment: What do the actual CSV files looks like, in your example?

Answer (score 0):

Does this help?

```
import os
import glob
import pandas as pd
os.chdir("C:\\Users\\ryans\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\schemas\\")


extension = 'csv'
all_filenames = [i for i in glob.glob('*.{}'.format(extension))]


#combine all files in the list
combined_csv = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(f) for f in all_filenames ])
#export to csv
combined_csv.to_csv( "C:\\combined.csv", index=False, encoding='utf-8-sig')
```

Or, this?

```
from glob import glob

with open('C:/main.csv', 'a') as singleFile:
    for csv in glob('C:/Users/*.csv'):
        if csv == 'main.csv':
            pass
        else:
            for line in open(csv, 'r'):
                singleFile.write(line)
```